# Java, gRPC and Context propagation

Tags: java, rpc, grpc, proto

Does anyone have a working example of **io.grpc.Context** propagation between client (stub) and server using gRPC in java?

My understanding is that it's not possible and I must use Metadata instead. Am I correct?

Online I have found only examples using *Header* rather than **Context**.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`io.grpc.Context` is for local propagation only, like between threads or even on the same thread. gRPC purposefully does not propagate items from it automatically. You can use a `ClientInterceptor` to copy a value from the `Context` to the `Metadata`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Out of curiosity, why is io.grpc.Context not propagated ?

Comment: What's propagated locally and remotely are fundamentally different. Context values aren't serialized, for instance. But even if they were, automatically sending arbitrary "ambient" values to remote hosts sounds scary and bug-prone. Context is similar to ThreadLocal; it'd be very strange to send ThreadLocals automatically to the remote.